# How can I prevent VS Code from automatically accepting the selected suggestion when typing a character like "("?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I generally like having JavaScript autocomplete suggestions in VS Code, but it drives me nuts that it automatically selects the first option when I am writing functions.

For instance, I want to call a function named `Setup` which IntelliSense may or may not yet know about. So I type in `Setup` and autocomplete suggests `SecurityPolicyViolationEvent`. When I type `(` it automatically takes `SecurityPolicyViolationEvent` and puts it in.

I have to type `Setup` then press `Escape` then press `(` (opening parenthesis / round brace).

The auto suggestions are at times helpful but I want to choose to select them when I want them, not "by default". How can I set VS Code so that I still get the suggestions but it doesn't select the first one automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the following in your settings.json file:

```json
"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
```

The setting's description:

> Controls whether suggestions should be accepted on commit characters. For example, in JavaScript, the semi-colon (`;`) can be a commit character that accepts a suggestion and types that character.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this setting:

```
Editor > Suggest: Selection Mode  

  // Controls whether a suggestion is selected when the widget shows.
  //  - always: Always select a suggestion when automatically triggering IntelliSense.
  //  - never: Never select a suggestion when automatically triggering IntelliSense.
  //  - whenTriggerCharacter: Select a suggestion only when triggering IntelliSense from a trigger character.
  //  - whenQuickSuggestion: Select a suggestion only when triggering IntelliSense as you type.

  "editor.suggest.selectionMode": "always",  // the default
```

Setting it to `never` for example will not select anything in the suggestion box.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> would then select the top entry.